# Load Gtk.Image from resource in GJS

Tags: gtk, gnome, gjs

I am trying to load a Gtk.Image from a resource but I can't figure it out what I am doing wrong.

I have the png in my gresource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
  <gresource prefix="/com/mydomain/MyApp">
    <file preprocess="xml-stripblanks">app-menu.ui</file>
    <file preprocess="xml-stripblanks">main.ui</file>
    <file>application.css</file>
    <file>logo.svg.png</file>
  </gresource>
</gresources>
```

And I am trying to load that png like this:

```
let imgWidget = new Gtk.Image();
imgWidget.set_from_resource('resource:///com/mydomain/MyApp/logo.svg.png');
```

But I always get a broken image.

Comment: Try without giving `resource:` prefix. Also, confirm wither the `gresources` file is mentioned for installation.

Comment: Yep, removing the resource:// fixed it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As niyasc pointed out, I had to remove the resource:// prefix